# How to map 4th, 5th and more buttons of the mouse to keyboard actions

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I am looking for a way to remap the four extra buttons I have on my mouse to keyboard functions like Ctrl, Shift, Enter and Delete

Comment: What OS? What application(s)?

Comment: What mouse? Often the manufacturer offers a special utility for configuring the buttons, like Logitech's SetPoint, Microsoft's IntelliPoint etc.

Comment: This is for windows and for some no name cheap mouse

Comment: buttons one and two are normal back and forward for browser, button three does exactly what left click does and the fourth button changes the cursor speed

Answer (score 1):

I used Auto Hot Key

XButton1::Ctrl etc

Comment: But there is no `XButton3+`.

Comment: I was reading up on that and there seems to be a more complex way to map XButton3 and others. I have mapped the first two and once I have worked out how to do the others I will edit my answer.

Comment: Please do. The Windows API supports buttons 4 & 5, so it’s trivial to capture them, but beyond that, it is manufacturer- and driver-dependent, so if there is indeed a way to work with them it would be very handy to know (at least for anyone who happens to have a mouse with that many buttons).